# Spivak Calculus problem with inductive proof of polynomial property

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Ok so I have been trying to do this proof of what seems to be a version of Factor theorem(I am now well versed in math so please forgive me if I am wrong).

Problem goes like this:

> > Prove that for any polynomial function f and any number a,there is polynomial g(x) such that f(x) = (x-a)g(x) + b .Proof is possible by induction on degree of polynomial

Proof for degree one is trivial.Now if we assume it is true for degree k we can proceed to prove for k+1.My proof for k+1 goes like this:

$f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + ... c_{k+1}x^{k+1} $ which is of degree k+1

Then we can assume that :

$f(x) - c_{k+1}x^{k+1} = (x-a)g(x) + b $    which is of degree k

Now my issue is that from this form I can not get the form required.Also proof from the answer book is not of much help.It goes like this:

> > Assume the preposition is true for degree k and we have:
> >     $$f(x) = a_{k+1}x^{k+1} + ... + a_1x + a_0 $$
> >
> > Now polynomial $$h(x) = f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a) $$ is of degree $\leq k$ so we can write:
> >
> > $$ f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-1) = (x-a)g(x) + b $$ or
> >     $$f(x)=(x-a)[g(x) + a_{k+1}] + b $$

My questions are :

1)How is h(x) of degree $\leq k $ when f(x) is k+1,should we not substract $a_{k+1}x^{k+1}$ to get lesser degree

2)How can we from first resulting form obtain the second one,since as far as I see in first form g(x) should be of degree k-1 ,and in second it should be k unless b or $a_{k+1}$ is of degree k+1 or k respectively

Please help .I have spent hours trying to figure this proof out,still does not make sense.

Problem can be found in Spivak Calculus vol.1 chapter 3 problem 7(a)

Comment: Note that this identity is the Ruffini rule and basis for the Horner scheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the answer as written is wrong; as you observe, the degree will only be reduced if we subtract the thing you recommended.

{In what follows, I'm using $c_i$ as the $i$th coefficient rather than $a_i$.}

But if you instead wrote
$$
f(x)−c_{k+1}(x^{k+1} - a x^{k})
$$
you'd still have a degree-$k$ polynomial, and could by induction write
$$
f(x)−c_{k+1}(x^{k+1} - a x^{k}) =(x−a)g(x)+b
$$
where $g$ is a degree-$(k-1)$ polynomial. 
Now moving things to the other side, you get
$$
f(x) = c_{k+1}(x^{k+1} - a x^{k}) + (x−a)g(x)+b \\
= c_{k+1}x^k (x- a) + (x−a)g(x)+b \\
$$
You can now combine the first two terms, and you're on your way!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can go the calculus route disregarding the hint and write for $u(t)=f(a+t(x-a))$

$$u(1)-u(0)=\int_0^1 u'(t)\,dt=\int_0^1 f'(a+t(x-a))(x-a)\,dt,$$

that is,

$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)\int_0^1 f'(a+t(x-a))\,dt.$$

Then note that the integrand is polynomial in $x$ of degree $\deg(f)-1$ and that as a linear property this remains invariant under integration.

Comment: You *could* do this, but at that point in Spivak's book, I believe that not even the derivative has been introduced; the integral certainly hasn't. It might be nice if he put the same problem, with a different hint, 10 chapters later, though, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that since $f(x)$ is a polynomial, it is defined over the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$.
Furthermore, the slope of the line running through the points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x \not = a$ is
$$g(x;a) = \frac{\mathrm{rise}}{\mathrm{run}} = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}.$$
For fixed $a$, let $f(a) = b$.
Then $(x-a)g(x) = f(x) - b$ and
$$f(x) = (x-a)g(x) + b.$$
Finally, note that although $g(x) = \infty$ at $x = a$,
$$f(a) = (a - a)g(a) + b = b$$
and is therefore consistent with the fact that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.